# Can't write code in FBrell code window

Tags: facebook

At fbrell.com I want to test some code and to see code of theirs existing examples. But, in none of the following browser IE8, FF3, Chrome I can't write anything in the text area. When I go to Save Code of an existing example there is for a second shown code of that example and after that it dissapears. Same thing happens at my home and my work PC.
Googling about this problem wasn't successful. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

FBrell console is implemented in Facebook, [JavaScript Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) try it if it didn't work, try clearing the cache.

Comment: Today it is working at fbrell.com and JavaScriptTestConsole in FB. It seems that yesterday there was some form of bug in fbrell.com. Even yesterday, I have found workaround by using Chrome Inspect Element I have found that for one text area there was style:display-none. I have removed it, and after that I was able to write&execute code from that text area.